# To reply or not to reply

Tags: meaning-in-context, email, correspondence

I was asked by a potential employer what time I would be available for a phone interview and they gave me the times available for them. I replied with a suitable time for me.  They responded with an email that read:

> Please allow this email to confirm a telephone interview with John and Jane
>   at 9am the 12th of...

Are they saying I don't need to reply?  Or should I reply to confirm the time?

Comment: Probably both (but don't pester them).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reply. The email is just their way of saying "we will arrange this time to call you". However, it shouldn't be a problem if you replied with something like "Thanks again for arranging this". Or, "I look forward to the interview, thanks again."